# AWS Application Load Balancer not loading one of the target groups pointing to same EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, sonarqube, aws-application-load-balancer

I have an EC2 instance which has two applications installed and configured

- Jenkins (Runs on port 8080 and I have configured it to use context path `/jenkins/`)
- SonarQube (Runs on port 9000 and I have configured it to use context path `/sonar/`)

When I simply hit public DNS of EC2 instance following happens

- http://sample-ec2-public-ip:8080/jenkins (Jenkins is loaded successfully)
- http://sample-ec2-public-ip:9000/sonar   (SonarQube is loaded successfully)

I add an Application Load Balancer with 2 target groups and 2 listener rules. Both of the target groups are pointing to the same EC2 instance for accessing SonarQube and Jenkins

- First listener rule points to 8080 port on path /jenkins/ to the ec2 instance
- Second listener rule points to 9000 port on path /sonar/  to the same ec2 instance

I have an AWS Route53 RecordSet which I am using to point to a domain. Here is the code for Route53 Record Set

```
   JenkinRecordSet:
    Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSetGroup
    Properties:
      HostedZoneName: mydomain.com.
      RecordSets:
      - Name: "jenkins.mydomain.com"
        Type: A
        AliasTarget:
          HostedZoneId: !GetAtt myALB.Outputs.albHostedZone
          DNSName: !GetAtt myALB.Outputs.albDNS

   SonarRecordSet:
    Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSetGroup
    Properties:
      HostedZoneName: mydomain.com.
      RecordSets:
      - Name: "sonar.mydomain.com"
        Type: A
        AliasTarget:
          HostedZoneId: !GetAtt myALB.Outputs.albHostedZone
          DNSName: !GetAtt myALB.Outputs.albDNS
```

Health checks are passed and I see both target groups register the same ec2 as healthy (one for sonar and other for jenkins on same ec2)

When I hit `jenkins.mydomain.com/jenkins` Jenkins is loaded perfectly fine and I can use it but when I hit `sonar.mydomain.com/sonar` Sonar is stuck at "Loading Screen". When I inspect the page I see that there are some JS files that Sonar is unable to find (404 error) and sonar freezes at loading.

This only happens when I put an application load balancer. When I access both Jenkins and Sonar via EC2 Public IP I can access both Jenkins and Sonar perfectly fine.

[image: Sonar Loading Stuck]

Can anyone help me resolve this issue with the Application Load Balancer? Is it suppose to be working like this?

Answer (score 0):

Sonar is client-side render, this is the root cause.

I suggest:

1. pointing to sonar without `path` (root path)
2. move build file to the right folder in public